# Turn On flashlight when camera is running

Tags: android, android-camera2

I would like to turn on the flashlight when the Camera is running but i am getting the following exception:

```
W/System.err: android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_IN_USE (4): setTorchMode:1611: Torch for camera "0" is not available due to an existing camera user
```

I am able to turn on the turn on the flashlight when the camera is not running, but when the camera is starting the flashlight is turn off and when i am pressing the button in my app to turn it on I am getting to above exception.

when I am using the flashlight system application, the flashlight is turn on also when the camera is running.

i was able to create a service to turn on the flashlight and it the service is working, but again, when the camera is running, i am getting the above exception.

here is my Service Class:

```
public class FlashLightService extends Service {
    private CameraManager camManager;
    private String cameraId;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        camManager = (CameraManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            Log.i("CAMERA HAS FLASH:",
                "" + camManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId).get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE));
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
            Log.i("CAMERA TURN ON", "cameraId=" + cameraId);
            camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            Log.i("CAMERA TURN OFF", "cameraId=" + cameraId);
            camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

here is the relevant code at the activity:

```
toggleFlashlightButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (isFlashOn) {
            setFlashOff();
        } else {
            setFlashOn();
        }
    }
});

private void setFlashOn() {
    isFlashOn = true;
    toggleFlashlightButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.flashlight_off);
    startService(flashLightService);
}

private void setFlashOff() {
    isFlashOn = false;
    toggleFlashlightButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.flashlight_on);
    stopService(flashLightService);
}
```

I am actually want to be able to activate the flashlight together with the camera from my application.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324647/flashlight-camera2-api

Comment: Thanks, but it is not help me to much since I am not holding the Camera object nor the Capcure Session object. I am using the following APPRTC implemntaion: https://github.com/androidthings/sample-videoRTC. is there anyway that i can turn on the flashlight in parallel to the Camera?

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar problem, I solved using JavaCameraView, and in the method `initializeCamera` in line 171 I add this `params.setFlashMode(params.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);`